# how to select by text using selenium and c#

Tags: c#, testing, selenium-webdriver

I need to select the value (hours) related to an specific date. For example in the html below I need to read the number 24:20 based on the number 6;
this is the html:

```
<div class="day-ofmonth">
<div class="day-ofmonth">
<span class="day-num">6</span>
<span class="available-time">24:20</span>
</div>
<div class="day-ofmonth">
<span class="day-num">7</span>
<span class="available-time">133:50</span>
</div>
<div class="day-ofmonth">
<div class="day-ofmonth">
```

if I use:

```
IWebElement t_value = d.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*     [@id='calinfo']/div[9]/span[2]"));
var t_again2 = t_value.GetAttribute("textContent");
```

i will get 24:20; but i need to get the value 24:20(in this case) based on number 6 (6 refers to day of the month) and not the Xpath (everyday will be a different date).  If anyone can point me in the right direction, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
string availableTime = null;
// Find all elements with class = 'day-num'
var dayNums = d.FindElements(By.XPath("//span[@class='day-num']"));
foreach (IWebElement dayNum in dayNums)
{
    // check if text is equal to 6
    if (dayNum.Text == "6")
    {
        // get the following sibling with class = 'available-time', then get the text
        availableTime = dayNum.FindElement(By.XPath("following-sibling::span[@class='available-time']")).Text; 
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: it does find the element but output is :OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement

Comment: `.Text` property will get the text content from the `WebElement` though. Are you miscalling `ToString()` instead? I would suggest you to debug what the WebElement you are getting.

Comment: Thank you, i was able to get around by dividing the xpath as a string and parsing table using [i]:xpath(stringXpath). stringXpath= one + i +two

Answer (score 0):

```
xpath=//span[text()='6')]/following-sibling::span[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner solution:

```
string availableTime = d.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='day-num' and text()='6']/following-sibling::span[@class='available-time']")).Text;
```

Comment: It is technically the same code as my previous one, but all done in Selenium. You might have parent/ ancestor Element that hide the Element you are looking.

Comment: Thank you, i was able to get around by dividing the xpath as a string and parsing table using [i]:xpath(stringXpath). stringXpath= one + i +two